# How to push the Webpack bundled files to Github repo?

Tags: github, webpack

In my first project using Webpack, Babel, React => i would like to push **only** the build output to remote github repo.
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to track the output in git? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to export the build files to a repo. Is this a thing?  Not the whole development file structure.